# Plotting Error with apa_linplot in papaja: Error in min(0, y.values[, "lower_limit"],

Tags: r, plot, papaja

Hey folks I have some issues using papaja plot functions.

I have this kind of data. frame in long format

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   MemSetSize, UpdatingSteps [6]
  Subject MemSetSize UpdatingSteps meanACC
    <int> <fct>      <fct>           <dbl>
1       1 3          0               0.958
2       1 3          2               1    
3       1 3          4               1    
4       1 5          0               0.957
5       1 5          2               1    
6       1 5          4               1
```

Which I try to plot very simple for the beginning:

```
papaja::apa_lineplot(Plot_ACC
                    , id ="Subject"
                    , dv ="meanACC"
                    ,factors = "MemSetSize", "UpdatingSteps")
```

If I don't define the factors, it works but it is useless as you can imagine. If I try it with the code above, I get this error:

```
Error in min(0, y.values[, "lower_limit"], aggregated[, dv], na.rm = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I'm really helpless and maybe it is related to some issues with other packages, but even if I unload all unnecessary libraries, it is still not working. If I use the aov objects from afex it works, but I can't change the factors assignment to the axis. Here are my loaded packages:

```
library(readr)
library(afex)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggpol)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(psych)
library(devtools)
library(papaja)
library(sjstats)
library(xtable)
library(emmeans)
library(BANOVA)
```

Maybe somebody has a clue about that?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for reaching out. I could reproduce your problem and just committed a code change to github that should resolve your problem. Just install papaja anew and everything should work as expected:

```
devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja")
```

Comment: You are welcome ! Thanks! It's working now as it should !